# Transformation using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I currently manually do my DTO => ViewModel transformations in my MVC project. So, the code looks like this:

```
var model = new LandingModel {
                FamilyName = token.FamilyName,
                LoggedInUser = token.DisplayName,
                TimeZoneName = token.TimeZoneName,
                CurrentDateTime = Common.SessionManager.GetSessionDate().ToString(SharedLib.Constants.FMT_DATE_AND_TIME_LONG)
            };
```

A LandingModel looks like this:

```
public class LandingModel
{
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
    public string LoggedInUser { get; set; }
    public string TimeZoneName { get; set; }
    public string CurrentDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

How do I handle then CurrentDateTime? It's a string in the model, and is handled via by getting the users timezone date time from a session variable, and applying a string format.

How can I do this using `Mapper.Map<SessionToken>(model));`

Note, .GetSessionDate() simply takes UTC date, and adds an offset from the users timezone, to give the current date according to them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can handle this scenario in your `MapperConfiguration` as indicated below:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(
   cfg =>
   {
      cfg.CreateMap<SessionToken, LandingModel>()
         .AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.CurrentDateTime = Common.SessionManager.GetSessionDate().ToString(SharedLib.Constants.FMT_DATE_AND_TIME_LONG));
   });
```

REFERENCE:

[AutoMapper - Before and after map actions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Before-and-after-map-actions)